# pyglet - video does not run smootly

Tags: python-2.7, video, pyglet

I have code written in python which should play a video file. Issue is the played video is not smooth compared to basic players. I have tried implement FPS indicator but it definitely does not reflect reality. Please help anyone.

```
import pyglet

vidPath="video.avi"

window = pyglet.window.Window(fullscreen = False,
                              resizable = True,
                              caption = 'Video')

window.set_mouse_visible(False)

player = pyglet.media.Player()

MediaLoad = pyglet.media.load(vidPath)

player.queue(MediaLoad)

player.play()

fps_display = pyglet.clock.ClockDisplay(
    format='%(fps).1f',
    color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1)
    )


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    player.get_texture().blit(0,0)
    fps_display.draw()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: Having some slight issues testing this. Most of the videos I've got laying around ends up black and won't show anything at all (the video files are encoded kinda shady tho and trying to pass them through ffmpeg gives me a bunch of errors). Do you happen to have a video that you've tested with that we can download ourselves?

Answer (score 0):

I actually noticed a lot of studder in your video.
I'm guessing this is because of the use of `blit()` instead of `draw()`+`window.flip()` which would be much more efficient at updating the graphical buffer.

It's also possible to put the texture of `player` into a `pyglet.sprite.Sprite()` object and the texture in itself will update on every frame but at a higher rate.

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from threading import *

# REQUIRES: AVBin
#pyglet.options['audio'] = ('alsa', 'openal', 'silent')
key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(main, self).__init__(800, 800, fullscreen = False)
        self.x, self.y = 0, 0

        self.player = pyglet.media.Player()
        self.player.queue(pyglet.media.load("video.mp4"))
        self.sprites = {'video' : None}

        self.alive = 1

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        pass

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, button, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == 65307: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0
        elif symbol == key.LCTRL:
            self.player.play()

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        if self.player.playing:
            if self.sprites['video'] is None:
                texture = self.player.get_texture()
                if texture:
                    self.sprites['video'] = pyglet.sprite.Sprite(texture)
            else:
                self.sprites['video'].draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

This doubled the frame rate for me, however I'm having some other glitches with my `.mp4` video as well as driver issues on my Windows machine, but it's working better than the example code you've found.

Comment: Need admit I already solved this issue by using VLC bindings. However I have wanted to appreciate your effort and try your code but it doesn't work for me. When I run a video, it plays audio but display no video - only black screen.

Comment: @TomášVavřinka I checked on my Windows box at home, I do get the same thing you're describing but when I move the window (wiggle it around) the graphics works. I'll have to check in on this and see why this happens.

Comment: I am not sure if it has an effect but going on Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

When I play video with pyglet 1.2.4 on my mac, it's not smooth at all. After upgrading pyglet to 1.5.6， the problem solved, as smooth as basic players. code snippet:

```
import pyglet

source = pyglet.media.load(VIDEO_FILE_PATH)
fmt = source.video_format

player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(source)
player.play()

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=fmt.width, height=fmt.height)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    player.get_texture().blit(0, 0)

pyglet.app.run()
```

However, pyglet 1.5.6 is not working on my Windows 10, the video will run slightly not smooth by 1.2.4 version on this machine.
So my best choice at the moment is: Mac + pyglet 1.5.6